Accessing Nested Values in Dataclasses(Polars )
Polars(0.20.31)
How to access nested values in dataclass fields ?
Tried 3 different ways to access them , but each way has some issue.
CODE:
from dataclasses import dataclass
import polars as pl

@dataclass
class Long:
    trader_a: int
    trader_b: int
    trader_c: int

data = {
    "Ticker": ["AAPL", "GOOGL", "MSFT"],
    "Market_Long": [
        Long(trader_a=1, trader_b= 2, trader_c=3),
        Long(trader_a=1,trader_b=2, trader_c= 3),
        Long(trader_a=1,trader_b=2, trader_c=3)
    ]
}
Total_df = pl.DataFrame(data)
print("Total_df")
print(Total_df)
print(Total_df["Market_Long"][0])


def AnalyzePositions_Alias( col_name):
    sum_shares = col_name[0]['trader_a']+col_name['trader_b']+col_name['trader_c']
    print("sum_shares")
    print(sum_shares)
    
    return sum_shares

# Try 1 (aliasing column name doesn't work as map_element on dataclass field returns a dict)
TotalAnalysis_df = Total_df.select(

    "Ticker",
    # AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'alias'
    # pl.col("Market_Long").map_elements(function=AnalyzePositions_Alias,return_dtype=pl.Int32,pass_name=True).alias("Sum_Market_Long")

    pl.col("Market_Long").map_elements(function=AnalyzePositions_Alias,return_dtype=pl.Int32,pass_name=True),


    )



# Try 2 & 3 (processing column entirely in a function)

# def AnalyzePositions_returnProcessedColumn( df,col_name):
#
#   return df.select(
#       "Ticker",
#       #Try2 - TypeError: 'Expr' object is not subscriptable"
#       pl.struct([pl.col(col_name)["trader_a"], pl.col(col_name)["trader_b"], pl.col(col_name)["trader_c"]]).sum().alias("Processed_Market_Long")
#
#       #Try3- WORKS but Calculated sum is WRONG . total value of all the indices is calucated as opposed to individual index
#       (pl.col(col_name).struct.field("trader_a") + pl.col(col_name).struct.field("trader_b") + pl.col(
#           col_name).struct.field("trader_c")).sum().alias("Sum_Market_Long")
# )
#
# TotalAnalysis_df = AnalyzePositions_returnProcessedColumn(df= Total_df.clone(),col_name="Market_Long")
#
# print(TotalAnalysis_df)

